# What is the value shown for memory graph in XenCenter?

Tags: linux, xen, memory-usage, xencenter

I would like to ask question to people in this community about Xen Center.

I use Xen 6.5 in production environment. However, I quite don't understand
the value shown in memory graph of "Performance" tab in each server.
My purpose is to exactly understand the value used and use for troubleshooting.

[image: memory graph in xen center]

Could someone educate me which command does Xen use to calculate the memory, or perhaps script?

Thanks,
Yu